# ¿Por qué "pepito" es un "bocadillo de carne"?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, comida

**"Pepito"** figura en el Diccionario de la Lengua desde 1984 como "**bocadillo de pan y carne**", cambiado en 1985 a "bocadillo que tiene dentro un ***filete*** de carne", definicion que se conserva hasta la edición [**actual**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SW9aQp7).

En ninguna de las ediciones se aclara nada sobre la etimología. ¿Alguna idea de por qué **pepito** es un bocadillo de pan y carne y, más específicamente, de un ***filete*** de carne?

Comment: Very interesting question. Aquí en Andalucía, en algunas regiones se considera un "pepito" simplemente a un bollo pequeño de pan. Luego ya de qué lo rellenes es otra cosa...

Comment: Yo leí hace algún tiempo en una revista que venía de alguien llamado Pepito que un día pidió un bocadillo de ternera aburrido del embutido de siempre, a partir de ahí la gente en ese bar empezó a pedir "uno como el de Pepito" y así se quedó con el nombre de Pepito de ternera. No me acuerdo donde lo leí pero supongo que se podrá encontrar alguna referencia a esa historia

Answer (score 1):

> Este madrileñísimo bocado apareció en los felices años veinte en uno de los famosos cafés o templos de la tertulia que se repartían por la ciudad. Se trataba del **Café de Fornos**, de la calle Alcalá.
>
> Una noche uno de los clientes, que cuenta la leyenda que era el hijo del dueño del establecimiento, cansado de cenar siempre el mismo bocadillo de fiambre decidió pedir un filete de ternera entre dos panes bien crujientes. Este cliente recibía el nombre de "Pepito". El resto de comensales absortos al ver la creación del joven, comenzaron a pedir bocadillos "como el de Pepito".
>
> Poco a poco fue popularizándose, y el nombre se acortó a "P**epito de ternera**". El Café de Fornos cerró sus puertas hace casi un siglo. En cambio, su plato estrella ha continuado más vivo que nunca. Echando un pulso con el famoso bocata de calamares, el pepito se coloca en la parte de arriba del ranking de las comidas madrileñas más populares.

Fuente:
http://www.sabormadrid.es/novedades/curiosidades/origen-pepito-ternera.php